# How to avoid implicit template instantiation of an unused template argument type of a class template when its instance is passed to a function?

Tags: c++, templates

A class template is implicitly instantiated only when its definition is required:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7731106/14196177
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Implicit_instantiation

However, if a template class instance is passed to a function, the instance's template argument gets instantiated, even though it's not used in any way. If the template argument is a template class specialization that contains invalid code for its template argument, an unnecessary compilation error occurs.

```
struct Abstract { virtual void pure() = 0; };

template<class Type> struct Invalid { Type Member; };

template<class> struct Example { void foo() {} };

template<class Type> void Test(Type&&) {}


int main()
{
    Example<Invalid<Abstract>> Object;
    Object.foo(); // No problem.
    Test(Object); // Error because of Invalid<Abstract>::Member.
    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly, there is no error if the template argument class `Invalid` is an incomplete type, that is, if it's not defined at all.

Why does an unused template argument type get instantiated when an instance of the template class is passed to a function? How to avoid such instantiation?

Comment: wrapping Test seems to remove the error ```struct S { template<class Type> static void Test(Type&&) {} }; S::Test(Object);```

Comment: wrapping Test with a namespace seem to work too but only if its not directed

Comment: @B.D Indeed! I found out that the function can be global, but just needs to be qualified with the scope operator: `::Test(Object)`. So it seems that this instantiation occurs when the function is called with an unqualified name. The question remains why.